# apache zeppelin multi-node cluster

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have deployed a zeepline cluster (v0.10.1) with 2 nodes. "zeppelin.cluster.addr" is configured, notebook and interpreter are stored in hdfs, using nginx for load balancing. In use, I found that the task execution failed. Raft exception is displayed in the log, and metadata cannot be synchronized with each other.
How do I properly configure a zeppelin cluster. Thanks!

Related conf (zeppelin-site.xml)

```
<property>
 <name>zeppelin.cluster.addr</name>
 <value>10.1.106.26:6000,10.1.106.27:6000</value>
 <description></description>
</property>
```

Related logs (zeppelin-idox-eb26.log)：

```
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:07:35,496] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:35,496] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:36,106] ({Thread-13} ClusterManager.java[run]:266) - Raft incomplete initialization! retry[6210]
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:36,661] ({raft-server-10.1.106.26:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[warn]:230) - RaftServer{10.1.106.26:6000}{role=FOLLOWER} - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused: /10.1.106.27:6000
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:07:38,497] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:38,497] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:38,759] ({raft-server-10.1.106.26:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[warn]:230) - RaftServer{10.1.106.26:6000}{role=FOLLOWER} - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused: /10.1.106.27:6000
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:39,111] ({Thread-13} ClusterManager.java[run]:266) - Raft incomplete initialization! retry[6240]
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:40,627] ({raft-server-10.1.106.26:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[warn]:230) - RaftServer{10.1.106.26:6000}{role=FOLLOWER} - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused: /10.1.106.27:6000
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:07:41,498] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:41,498] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:42,115] ({Thread-13} ClusterManager.java[run]:266) - Raft incomplete initialization! retry[6270]
WARN [2023-03-21 18:07:42,129] ({raft-server-10.1.106.26:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[warn]:230) - RaftServer{10.1.106.26:6000}{role=FOLLOWER} - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused: /10.1.106.27:6000
```

Related logs (zeppelin-idox-eb26.log)：

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Creating process hdfs2-shared_process failed on remote server 10.1.106.27:6000
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:271)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:438)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creating process hdfs2-shared_process failed on remote server 10.1.106.27:6000
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.launcher.ClusterInterpreterLauncher.launchDirectly(ClusterInterpreterLauncher.java:177)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.launcher.InterpreterLauncher.launch(InterpreterLauncher.java:110)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSetting.createInterpreterProcess(InterpreterSetting.java:856)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:66)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:104)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:154)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:126)
... 13 more
```

Related logs (zeppelin-idox-eb27.log)：

```
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter neo4j status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter spark-yarn status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter sparql status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter kylin status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} FileSystemConfigStorage.java[save]:66) - Save Interpreter Settings to hdfs://idomp/zeppelin-conf/interpreter.json
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,155] ({main} FileSystemRecoveryStorage.java[<init>]:61) - Using folder hdfs://idomp/zeppelin-recovery to store recovery data
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:09:02,453] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:02,453] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,578] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:334) - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,361] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$start$0]:225) - Started
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,362] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$start$0]:225) - Started
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:09:05,779] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,118] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:331) - Started ServerConnector@306cf3ea{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{10.1.106.27:8899}
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,119] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:400) - Started @9748ms
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:11,120] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:265) - Done, zeppelin server started
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,462] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter scalding status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter livy status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter neo4j status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter spark-yarn status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter sparql status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter spark-yarn status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter sparql status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} InterpreterSetting.java[setStatus]:739) - Set interpreter kylin status to READY
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:01,463] ({main} FileSystemConfigStorage.java[save]:66) - Save Interpreter Settings to hdfs://idomp/zeppelin-conf/interpreter.json
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,155] ({main} FileSystemRecoveryStorage.java[<init>]:61) - Using folder hdfs://idomp/zeppelin-recovery to store recovery data
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,435] ({Thread-10} ClusterManagerServer.java[run]:161) - RaftServer run() >>>
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,438] ({Thread-12} ClusterManager.java[run]:221) - RaftClientThread run() >>>
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,439] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:251) - Starting zeppelin server
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,442] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:360) - jetty-9.4.31.v20200723; built: 2020-07-23T17:57:36.812Z; git: 450ba27947e13e66baa8cd1ce7e85a4461cacc1d; jvm 1.8.0_352-b08
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:09:02,453] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:02,453] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:02,459] ({Thread-12} NettyMessagingService.java[loadKeyStores]:270) - Disabling TLS for intra-cluster messaging; Could not load cluster key store: ../config/atomix.jks (No such file or directory)
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:02,459] ({Thread-10} NettyMessagingService.java[loadKeyStores]:270) - Disabling TLS for intra-cluster messaging; Could not load cluster key store: ../config/atomix.jks (No such file or directory)
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,566] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:276) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,578] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:334) - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,578] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:339) - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:02,582] ({main} HouseKeeper.java[startScavenging]:140) - node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,360] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$startAcceptingConnections$24]:605) - /10.1.106.27 accepting incoming connections on port 36769
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,360] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$startAcceptingConnections$24]:605) - /10.1.106.27 accepting incoming connections on port 6000
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,361] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$start$0]:225) - Started
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:03,362] ({netty-messaging-event-epoll-server-0} NettyMessagingService.java[lambda$start$0]:225) - Started
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:04,986] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:860) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@31be6b49{zeppelin-web,/,jar:file:///home/idox/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war!/,AVAILABLE}{/home/idox/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war}
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:05,003] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:276) - NO JSP Support for /next, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:09:05,779] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:05,779] ({Thread-11} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,095] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:860) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@771158fb{zeppelin-web-angular,/next,jar:file:///home/idox/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war!/,AVAILABLE}{/home/idox/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war}
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,118] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:331) - Started ServerConnector@306cf3ea{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{10.1.106.27:8899}
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,119] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:400) - Started @9748ms
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:06,178] ({Thread-13} ClusterManager.java[run]:266) - Raft incomplete initialization! retry[30]
ERROR [2023-03-21 18:09:06,687] ({Thread-10} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:341) - Raft incomplete initialization!
WARN [2023-03-21 18:09:06,687] ({Thread-10} ClusterManager.java[putClusterMeta]:369) - putClusterMeta failure, Cache metadata to queue.
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,687] ({Thread-10} ClusterManagerServer.java[run]:224) - RaftServer run() <<<
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,688] ({raft-server-10.1.106.27:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[info]:170) - RaftServer{10.1.106.27:6000} - Transitioning to FOLLOWER
INFO [2023-03-21 18:09:06,909] ({raft-server-10.1.106.27:6000} DelegatingLogger.java[info]:170) - RaftServer{10.1.106.27:6000} - Found leader 10.1.106.26:6000
```

Comment: please add the logs as text to your question (format it with code fences) instead of images. It seems as if you anonymized IP addresses - if you use private IP addresses like 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x or 192.168.x.x you don't have to do that, the servers are not reachable from public internet. Or you replace the addresses in the logs with such private IP addresses instead of removing them.
Also put the _full_ stacktrace into your question as text please.

Comment: The log of zeppelin has been added.

Comment: The essential part of the logs seems to be `Connection refused: /10.1.106.27:6000` - what do the logs of that server say? Did that server come up? Also the `/` in front of the IP address in that message is weird, I would expect a plain IP address without that prefix.

Comment: the  zeppelin-site.xml and the log of zeppelin 106.27 has been added.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no expert at Apache Zeppelin config, but if the servers run on Linux, you could try to check if maybe the firewall config or AppArmor are preventing access to the network. (Firewall could also be an issue on other OS)